# Comparing multiple columns in .apply() pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write an .apply() function that compares a column of my main df and a column of a separate df and returns a string. I want to make a new column in my main df with the apply function. The code is as follows:

```
def a_by_a(row):
    if row.loc['a'] > df.groupby(['a_bins']).mean()['a'][str(row.loc['a_bins'])]:
        return "Above average"
    else:
        return "Below average"

df['a_gby_b'] = df.apply(a_by_a,axis=1)
```

I'm trying to compare what's in column a with the average of a grouped by a_bins, where I have binned the data. When I run this code, I get this error:

```
('bin #1', 'occurred at index 0')
```

However, I made a test function to try out `[str(row.loc['a_bins'])]` (where I get my error) that works:

```
def test(row):
    return str(row.loc['a']) + str(row.loc['bins'])
df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we can do it with `transform` and `np.where`

```
df['New']=np.where(df['a']>df.groupby(['a_bins'])['a'].transform('mean'),
                   'Above average',
                   'Below average')
```